# How to check whether a subset of dictionary items exists in another list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I have a list of dictionaries (called "primer names") that holds the following information:

```
{'part number': 1, 'notes': 'Fw Gibson primer on pEM113 to extract CmR resistance and pSC101 backbone and T7 promoter and term.', 'direction': 'fw primer', 'construct': '24', 'source': 'pEM113'}
{'part number': 1, 'notes': 'Re Gibson primer on pEM113 to extract CmR resistance and pSC101 backbone and T7 promoter and term.', 'direction': 're primer', 'construct': '24', 'source': 'pEM113'}
{'part number': 2, 'notes': 'Fw Gibson primer on BBa_K274100 to extract crtEBI operon', 'direction': 'fw primer', 'construct': '24', 'source': 'BBa_K274100'}
{'part number': 2, 'notes': 'Re Gibson primer on BBa_K274100 to extract crtEBI operon', 'direction': 're primer', 'construct': '24', 'source': 'BBa_K274100'}
{'part number': 1, 'notes': 'Fw Gibson primer on pEM114 to extract CmR resistance and pSC101 backbone and K1F promoter and term.', 'direction': 'fw primer', 'construct': '25', 'source': 'pEM114'}
{'part number': 1, 'notes': 'Re Gibson primer on pEM114 to extract CmR resistance and pSC101 backbone and K1F promoter and term.', 'direction': 're primer', 'construct': '25', 'source': 'pEM114'}
```

I have another list of dictionaries (called "primer sequences") that holds the following information:

```
{'Part Number': '1', 'Construct Number': '24', 'Direction': 're primer', 'Primer Sequence': 'agaccgtcatctagtacctcTCTCCCTATAGTGAGTCGTATTACTCTAGAAGCGGCCGCg'}
{'Part Number': '1', 'Construct Number': '24', 'Direction': 'fw primer', 'Primer Sequence': 'tggaggatctgatataataaTAGCATAACCCCTTGGGGCCTCTAAACGGGTCTTGAGGGG'}
{'Part Number': '2', 'Construct Number': '24', 'Direction': 'fw primer', 'Primer Sequence': 'TACGACTCACTATAGGGAGAgaggtactagatgacggtctgcgcaaaaaaacacgttcat'}
{'Part Number': '2', 'Construct Number': '24', 'Direction': 're primer', 'Primer Sequence': 'GGCCCCAAGGGGTTATGCTAttattatatcagatcctccagcatcaaacctgctgtcgct'}
{'Part Number': '1', 'Construct Number': '25', 'Direction': 're primer', 'Primer Sequence': 'agaccgtcatctagtacctcTCTCCCTATAGTGATAGTTATTACTCTAGAAGCGGCCGCg'}
{'Part Number': '1', 'Construct Number': '25', 'Direction': 'fw primer', 'Primer Sequence': 'tggaggatctgatataataaTAGCATAACCCCTTGGGGCCTCTAAACGGGTCTTGAGGGG'}
{'Part Number': '2', 'Construct Number': '25', 'Direction': 'fw primer', 'Primer Sequence': 'TAACTATCACTATAGGGAGAgaggtactagatgacggtctgcgcaaaaaaacacgttcat'}
{'Part Number': '2', 'Construct Number': '25', 'Direction': 're primer', 'Primer Sequence': 'GGCCCCAAGGGGTTATGCTAttattatatcagatcctccagcatcaaacctgctgtcgct'}
```

My goal is to combine the information contained in both, such that I get an output that has part number, construct number, direction, primer sequence, notes, construct and source for each primer (fw or re) in the bottom list. In order to match "primer name" to "primer sequence", I have to check to make sure that their "part number", "construct number" and "direction" are all the same.

I've tried the following code to check this, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
for row in primers_names_list: #recall that primers_names_list is a list of dictionaries
    if any({x['Part Number'], x['Construct Number'], x['Direction']} == {row['part number'], row['construct number'], row['direction']} for x in primers_without_names):
        primers_with_names.append({'part number':row['part number'], 'construct number':row['construct number'], 'notes':row['notes'], 'primer sequence':x['Primer Sequence']})
```

Can anybody provide a hint as to how I can accomplish this please?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems:

1. `part number` is an `int` in *primer names* and a `str` in *primer sequences*. For a comparison to yield `True` you'd have to either convert the `int` to a `str` (using *str(val)*) or the `str` to an int (using *int(val)*)
2. The key names you are using in your loop are throwing `KeyError` exceptions, because they are incorrect (notice that *primer sequences* has `Construct Number` and *primer names* has `construct`)

Here is a working code sample:

```
primers_names_list = [
{'part number': 1, 'notes': 'Fw Gibson primer on pEM113 to extract CmR resistance and pSC101 backbone and T7 promoter and term.', 'direction': 'fw primer', 'construct': '24', 'source': 'pEM113'},
{'part number': 1, 'notes': 'Re Gibson primer on pEM113 to extract CmR resistance and pSC101 backbone and T7 promoter and term.', 'direction': 're primer', 'construct': '24', 'source': 'pEM113'},
{'part number': 2, 'notes': 'Fw Gibson primer on BBa_K274100 to extract crtEBI operon', 'direction': 'fw primer', 'construct': '24', 'source': 'BBa_K274100'},
{'part number': 2, 'notes': 'Re Gibson primer on BBa_K274100 to extract crtEBI operon', 'direction': 're primer', 'construct': '24', 'source': 'BBa_K274100'},
{'part number': 1, 'notes': 'Fw Gibson primer on pEM114 to extract CmR resistance and pSC101 backbone and K1F promoter and term.', 'direction': 'fw primer', 'construct': '25', 'source': 'pEM114'},
{'part number': 1, 'notes': 'Re Gibson primer on pEM114 to extract CmR resistance and pSC101 backbone and K1F promoter and term.', 'direction': 're primer', 'construct': '25', 'source': 'pEM114'},
]

primers_without_names = [
{'Part Number': '1', 'Construct Number': '24', 'Direction': 're primer', 'Primer Sequence': 'agaccgtcatctagtacctcTCTCCCTATAGTGAGTCGTATTACTCTAGAAGCGGCCGCg'},
{'Part Number': '1', 'Construct Number': '24', 'Direction': 'fw primer', 'Primer Sequence': 'tggaggatctgatataataaTAGCATAACCCCTTGGGGCCTCTAAACGGGTCTTGAGGGG'},
{'Part Number': '2', 'Construct Number': '24', 'Direction': 'fw primer', 'Primer Sequence': 'TACGACTCACTATAGGGAGAgaggtactagatgacggtctgcgcaaaaaaacacgttcat'},
{'Part Number': '2', 'Construct Number': '24', 'Direction': 're primer', 'Primer Sequence': 'GGCCCCAAGGGGTTATGCTAttattatatcagatcctccagcatcaaacctgctgtcgct'},
{'Part Number': '1', 'Construct Number': '25', 'Direction': 're primer', 'Primer Sequence': 'agaccgtcatctagtacctcTCTCCCTATAGTGATAGTTATTACTCTAGAAGCGGCCGCg'},
{'Part Number': '1', 'Construct Number': '25', 'Direction': 'fw primer', 'Primer Sequence': 'tggaggatctgatataataaTAGCATAACCCCTTGGGGCCTCTAAACGGGTCTTGAGGGG'},
{'Part Number': '2', 'Construct Number': '25', 'Direction': 'fw primer', 'Primer Sequence': 'TAACTATCACTATAGGGAGAgaggtactagatgacggtctgcgcaaaaaaacacgttcat'},
{'Part Number': '2', 'Construct Number': '25', 'Direction': 're primer', 'Primer Sequence': 'GGCCCCAAGGGGTTATGCTAttattatatcagatcctccagcatcaaacctgctgtcgct'},
]


primers_with_names = []
for row in primers_names_list: #recall that primers_names_list is a list of dictionaries
    for x in primers_without_names:
        if (
            int(x['Part Number']) == row['part number'] and
            x['Construct Number'] == row['construct'] and
            x['Direction'] == row['direction']
        ):
            primers_with_names.append(
                {
                    'part number': row['part number'], 
                    'construct number': row['construct'], 
                    'notes': row['notes'], 
                    'primer sequence':x['Primer Sequence']
                }
            )
            # If you are only expecting one match from the primers_without_names
            # collection, or wish to enforce that, you can add a break statement after
            # the insertion here to break out of the inner comparison loop and move on
            # to the next row item


for p in primers_with_names:
    print p

print
print len(primers_with_names)
```

**Edit:** Another option, if the comparison values are unique for each row in each collection, and if you have sufficient memory and don't mind pre-processing the lists, is to convert the two collections to dictionaries, keyed on a *(part number, construct number, direction)* tuple. This reduces the lookup effort later to amortized O(1) per row. Overall you'll get O(3N) instead of O(N^2), which is pretty good for large sets.

```
# convert both lists to dictionaries
primers_names_dict = { 
    (str(p['part number']), str(p['construct']), str(p['direction'])): p
    for p in primers_names_list 
}
primers_sequence_dict = {
    (str(p['Part Number']), str(p['Construct Number']), str(p['Direction'])): p
    for p in primers_without_names
}


# now that we have two dicts, we can do a key<->key match between them, so each
# comparison op is just a dictionary key lookup, which is O(1) on average
matches = []
for key in primers_names_dict.keys():
    if key in primers_sequence_dict: # amortized O(1) lookup
        matches.append( {
            'part number': primers_names_dict[key]['part number'], 
            'construct number': primers_names_dict[key]['construct'], 
            'notes': primers_names_dict[key]['notes'], 
            'primer sequence': primers_sequence_dict[key]['Primer Sequence']
        } )

for m in matches:
    print m
print len(matches)
```

Comment: Thank you Nisan! Didn't realize the small detail on data typing.

Comment: Fixed the data typing issue, and it works perfectly now. I converted everything to str(...).

Comment: One other problem I'm noticing is that the outer for loop only seems to run once. Do you notice that too, @Nisan.H?

Comment: In the loop above, every row in `primers_with_names_list` is matched against every row in `primers_without_names`, and for every successful a match, a new row is created and saved in `primers_with_names`. In your original code you used `any(...)` as the truth condition, and the `x` item was simply the last row from the second collection assigned to `x` in the `any` iterator before it yielded a `True`, which would be the equivalent of adding `break`  after appending to `primers_with_names` in the above nested for loop.

Comment: I'm not sure if your intended behaviour was to save the first valid match, or all valid matches, though. So, the above code with `break` after the `append()` step will only add the first valid match per row in the first collection (i.e. _at most len(primers_names_list) matches_), and without `break` will add all valid matches (i.e. _at most len(primers_names_list)*len(primers_without_names) matches_).

Comment: My intended behavior is that there is only one valid match each time, and that is by design in both lists. I used your code (nested for loop), but found that only one sequence-name match got appended out of the entire list. In theory, if I have n names, I should have n sequence-name matches, because in my complete list (the list I pasted was only partial), I have equal numbers of sequences and names.

Comment: Ahhh, I fixed it! It was a data typing issue again. Originally, my primers_without_names was a csv.DictReader object, so that was causing the problems with the code. Thanks again!

Comment: @ericmjl good to hear. I also added another optional method to get the matches, which pre-processes the data, but is faster for larger collections. It does require that the values used in the key tuples be unique, though.

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems here.

1. Part Number in one dictionary is an integer, in the other it's a string.
2. You put `row['construct number']` where I think it should be `row['construct']`

Here it is fixed:

```
for row in primers_names_list: #recall that primers_names_list is a list of dictionaries
    for x in primers_without_names:
        if {x['Part Number'], x['Construct Number'], x['Direction']} == {str(row['part number']), row['construct'], row['direction']}:
            primers_with_names.append({'part number':row['part number'], 'construct number':row['construct'], 'notes':row['notes'], 'primer sequence':x['Primer Sequence']})
```

Comment: #1 is definitely correct; #2 - it's `row['construct number']`. Thank you for the comment though, @jgritty!

Comment: It's definitely 'construct' though, lookie here: {'part number': 1, 'notes': 'Fw Gibson primer on pEM113 to extract CmR resistance and pSC101 backbone and T7 promoter and term.', 'direction': 'fw primer', **'construct'**: '24', 'source': 'pEM113'}